# Haskell split string on last occurence

Tags: list, haskell, split

Is there any way I can split String in Haskell on the last occurrence of given character into 2 lists?
For example I want to split list "a b c d e" on space into ("a b c d", "e").
Thank you for answers.

Comment: `breakLastSpace str = (reverse (drop 1 y), reverse x) where (x, y) = break (== ' ') $ reverse str` is a relatively naïve implementation.

Comment: note also, that you can split your string on spaces by the `words` function

Comment: Note, for what it's worth, that `text` has `breakOnEnd :: Text -> Text -> (Text, Text)` so that `T.breakOnEnd " "  "a b c d e" ` gives the desired result `("a b c d ","e")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why the solutions suggested are so complicated. Only **<s>one</s> two  traversals** are needed:

```
splitLast :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Either [a] ([a],[a])
splitLast c' = foldr go (Left [])
    where
        go c (Right (f,b)) = Right (c:f,b)
        go c (Left s) | c' == c = Right ([],s)
                      | otherwise = Left (c:s)
```

Note this is **total** and clearly signifies its failure. When a split is not possible (because the character specified wasn't in the string) it returns a `Left` with the original list. Otherwise, it returns a `Right` with the two components.

```
ghci> splitLast ' ' "hello beautiful world"
Right ("hello beautiful","world")
ghci> splitLast ' ' "nospaceshere!"
Left "nospaceshere!"
```

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest I've seen so far, but it actually performs two passes, one deconstructing the input and another constructing the output. It's therefore stricter than necessary, and slower for very long lists. You can fix this, but avoiding the risk of memory leaks could be a bit tricky.

Comment: @dfeuer Thank you for the correction. I always forget the structure has to be built back up. The alternative you mention would be a left fold?

Comment: Hrmmm... What I was thinking won't work. I think the only lazy way is to accumulate a chunk and wait to see if it should be attached to the end.

Answer (score 2):

Its not beautiful, but it works:

```
import Data.List
f :: Char -> String -> (String, String)
f char str = let n = findIndex (==char) (reverse str) in
                case n of
                  Nothing -> (str, [])
                  Just n  -> splitAt (length str - n -1) str
```

I mean `f 'e' "a b c d e" = ("a b c d ", "e")`, but I myself wouldn't crop that trailing space.

Comment: Might as well make it `a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`, no?

Comment: @chris martin Sure, do as you like, I just wanted to make clear how to use that function in this context by providing that typesignature.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with more pattern matching.

```
import Data.List

splitLast = contract . words
    where contract [] = ("", "")
          contract [x] = (x, "")
          contract [x,y] = (x, y)
          contract (x:y:rest) = contract $ intercalate " " [x,y] : rest
```

For long lists, we just join the first two strings with a space and try the shorter list again. Once the length is reduced to 2, we just return the pair of strings.

`(x, "")` seemed like a reasonable choice for strings with no whitespace, but I suppose you could return `("", x)` instead.

It's not clear that `("", "")` is the best choice for empty strings, but it seems like a reasonable alternative to raising an error or changing the return type to something like `Maybe (String, String)`.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose the following solution:

```
splitLast list elem = (reverse $ snd reversedSplit, reverse $ fst reversedSplit)
  where 
  reversedSplit = span (/= elem) $ reverse list
```

probably not the fastest one (two needless reverses) but I like it's simplicity.

If you insist on removing the space we're splitting on, you can go for:

```
import qualified Data.List as List
splitLast list elem = splitAt (last $ List.elemIndices elem list) list
```

however, this version assumes that there will be at least one element matching the pattern. If you don't like this assumption, the code gets slightly longer (but no double-reversals here):

```
import qualified Data.List as List
splitLast list elem = splitAt index list where
    index = if null indices then 0 else last indices
    indices = List.elemIndices elem list
```

Of course, choice of splitting at the beginning is arbitrary and probably splitting at the end would be more intuitive for you - then you can simply replace `0` with `length list`

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to split at every occurrence and then separate the initial parts from the last part.

Pointed:

```
import Control.Arrow   -- (&&&)
import Data.List       -- intercalate
import Data.List.Split -- splitOn
breakOnLast :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
breakOnLast x = (intercalate x . init &&& last) . splitOn x
```

Point-free:

```
liftA2 (.) ((&&& last) . (. init) . intercalate) splitOn

(.) <$> ((&&&) <$> ((.) <$> pure init <*> intercalate) <*> pure last) <*> splitOn
```

Comment: I'm not sure the point-free versions are even worth mentioning.

Comment: It should be mentioned that `Data.List.Split` is provided by the `split` package.

Comment: I like finding point-free versions, and I like them, so I give them :)