# Iterating through list in reverse

Tags: haskell

Assume the following (non-functioning) code, that takes a predicate such as `(==2)` and a list of integers, and drops only the last element of the list that satisfies the predicate:

```
cutLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
cutLast a [] = []
cutLast pred (as:a)
 | (pred) a == False = (cutLast pred as):a
 | otherwise         = as
```

This code does not work, so clearly lists cannot be iterated through in reverse like this. How could I implement this idea? I'm not 100% sure if the code is otherwise correct - but hopefully it gets the idea across.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect if there are no elements satisfying the condition? Return the list as is?

Comment: @Alec: Correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - Filter Last Element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864951/haskell-filter-last-element)

Comment: In case it's not clear, `[Int]` is likely a poor data structure for your problem (though we'd need to know the other operations you intend to support to suggest something better)

Comment: When writing that pseudocode, I was thinking of integers as possible test arguments - in my final code, I fixed this by using `cutLast :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple (but less efficient) solution is to implement `cutFirst` in a similar fashion to `filter`, then reverse the input to and output from that function.

```
cutLast pred = reverse . cutFirst . reverse
   where cutFirst [] = []
         cutFirst (x:xs) | pred x = xs
                         | otherwise = x : cutFirst xs
```

Comment: Alec's version is indeed the more efficient option, but this was much simpler for me to understand for a Haskell newbie like myself, so I am choosing this one. Equal thanks to both chepner and @Alec for their great work.

Answer (score 3):

Borrowing heavily from [myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40030460/haskell-split-string-on-last-occurence/40032635#40032635): the problem with this sort of question is that you don't know which element to remove until you get to the end of the list. Once we observe this, the most straightforward thing to do is traverse the list one way then back using `foldr` (the second traversal comes from the fact `foldr` is not tail-recursive).

The cleanest solution I can think of is to rebuild the list on the way back up, dropping the first element.

```
cutLast :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Either [a] [a]
cutLast f = foldr go (Left [])
    where
        go x (Right xs) = Right (x:xs)
        go x (Left xs) | f x = Right xs
                       | otherwise = Left (x:xs)
```

The return type is `Either` to differentiate between not found anything to drop from the list (`Left`), and having encountered and dropped the last satisfying element from the list (`Right`). Of course, if you don't care about whether you dropped or didn't drop an element, you can drop that information:

```
 cutLast' f = either id id . cutLast f
```

---

Following the discussion of speed in the comments, I tried swapping out `Either [a] [a]` for `(Bool,[a])`. Without any further tweaking, this is (as @dfeuer predicted) consistently a bit slower (on the order of 10%).

Using irrefutable patterns on the tuple, we can indeed avoid forcing the whole output (as per @chi's suggestion), which makes this much faster for lazily querying the output. This is the code for that:

```
cutLast' :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> (Bool,[a])
cutLast' f = foldr go (False,[])
    where
        go x ~(b,xs) | not (f x) = (b,x:xs)
                     | not b = (False,x:xs)
                     | otherwise = (True,xs)
```

However, this is 2 to 3 times slower than either of the other two versions (that don't use irrefutable patterns) when forced to normal form.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `(Bool, [a])` instead of the isomorphic type `Either [a] [a]`. That might feel more natural to those who use flags in imperative programming. From a FP perspective, I think both alternatives are OK.

Comment: @chi, I would consider the flag more natural in this case, but `Either` seems likely to perform better under GHC.

Comment: @dfeuer Interesting, I thought the opposite might be true in some cases. I mean, `(Bool,[a])` when `not (f x)` allows one to prepend `x` without forcing the evaluation of the flag, more lazily than what we could do with the sum type. The stricter sum type might perform better when `f x` is mostly true, though (?)

Comment: @chi, I haven't benchmarked this particular example, but I've seen sums work a lot faster than tags. I think maybe it has something to do with GHC pointer tagging, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: @chi  We _can_ tweak a tuple version of this so that the output can be queried lazily, but that version ends up much slower than anything else I tried if we force the whole output.

Comment: @dfeuer The sum types are indeed a bit faster than tuples for going to normal form.

Comment: I also want to add that it is possible to improve this code in order to make it more lazy. You version will hang in case of such call: `take 10 $ cutLast' (== 0) [1..]` and will introduce extra overhead in general.

Comment: @Shersh Look again. `cutLast'` will not hang on the example you gave (if you fix the types: `take 10 $ snd $ cutLast' (== 0) [1..]`). But you are right - as a result of not hanging on that example, it will pay the price of having extra overhead.